# Converting types in c#

Tags: c#, list, foreach, filter, model

Is there a better way to write this without the foreach?
I want to add items (Jurisdictions) from the IEnumerable of type int and convert into an IList which contains the property Ref and should be set in there.

```
public class TrackDataFilter
{
    public TrackDataFilter(IEnumerable<int> firmRef, int? superSectorRef, DateTime from, DateTime to, int userFirmRef) : this()
    {
        Firms = firmRef.Select(x => new TrackFilterGenericRef { Ref = x, Type = ContentTypes.Firm, Description = "" });
        SuperSectorRef = superSectorRef;
        From = from;
        To = to;
        UserFirmRef = userFirmRef;
    }

    public TrackDataFilter()
    {
        Workareas = new List<TrackFilterGenericRef>();
        Jurisdictions = new List<TrackFilterGenericRef>();
        Tags = new List<TrackFilterGenericRef>();
        Firms = Enumerable.Empty<TrackFilterGenericRef>();
    }

    public IList<TrackFilterGenericRef> Jurisdictions { get; set; } 
    ...
}   

public class TaxiBriefingFilter
{

    public IEnumerable<int> Jurisdictions { get; set; }
    ...
}

// add items in IEnumerable<int> Jurisdictions into IList<TrackFilterGenericRef>

var filter = new TaxiBriefingFilter();

var dataFilter = new TrackDataFilter(new int[] { companyId }, null, from, to, userFirmRef);

foreach (var jurisdictionRef in filter.Jurisdictions)
{
    dataFilter.Jurisdictions.Add(new TrackFilterGenericRef { Ref = jurisdictionRef});
}

var jurisdictions = trackAnalyticsService.GetJurisdictions(dataFilter, maxJurisdictions);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can express the same logic using LINQ, but in this case I don't think it's easier to read.  Performance ought to be about the same.

```
using System.Linq;
...
var filter = new TaxiBriefingFilter();
var dataFilter = new TrackDataFilter(new int[] { companyId }, null, from, to, userFirmRef);
dataFilter.Jurisdictions.AddRange(
    filter.Jurisdictions.Select(jref => new TrackFilterGenericRef { Ref = jref }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
using System.Linq;
...
Jurisdictions = Firms.ToList();
```

or

```
Jurisdictions = firmRef.Select(x => new TrackFilterGenericRef { Ref = x, Type = ContentTypes.Firm, Description = "" }).ToList();
```

?

In the first example, you would get a list with the same instances as in the `Firms` enumerable.
In the second you would get a list with new instances in the `Jurisdictions` list.